# How to convert row data into different columns in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, crosstab

```
PONumbe     LNSKU   LNStyleNo   LNStyl  LNColor counter SizeDescription
164874      1059656 12345678910 LALALA  RED     1       050B
164874      1059656 12345678910 LALALA  RED     2       055B
```

I want to convert values of SizeDescription and counter into multiple columns based on different combination of PONumbe LNSKU

output should be like this

```
PONumbe LNSKU    LNStyleNo    LNStyl    LNColor counter SizeDesc50 SizeDesc50_Count SizeDesc55 SizeDesc55_Count
164874  1059656  12345678910  LALALA    RED     1       050B        1                 055B        2
```

I cannot figure out how to write T-SQL query for this.

Thanks

Comment: Will there always be two rows per key (POnumbe)?   Can there be more than just 050B and 055B?

Comment: That is certainly possible in SQL, but I'd almost try writing that in a scripting language. It would probably be easier, especially if SizeDescription takes on more than just those two values.'

Comment: This is easy in SQL if you have 2 rows only to go side by side. or you want MIN/MAX etc. If you had 4 rows, then what to put in the extra columns where you only have 2 rows? 15 rows to give 15 sets of columns? And give us more sample data please in case there are other issues

Comment: @Sparky there can be more than just 050B and 055B.

Comment: @gbn possible values are 055B 60B 65B 70B upto 13B so I can have upto 26 Rows. It is completely possible that some of these rows are missing. If these rows are missing i would still like there values to be present in thr respective columns(SizeDesc50 ,SizeDesc55,SizeDesc60 etc) but in Count columns (SizeDesc50_count,SizeDesc55_count etc) I would default value to be 0. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.counter AS [Size For 050], t3.counter AS [Size for 055]
FROM table t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table t2 ON t2.key = t1.key AND SizeDescription LIKE '050%'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table t3 ON t3.key = t1.key AND SizeDescription LIKE '055%'
```

That should give you a start... if you let me know more about the schema, maybe I could flesh it out a bit..

Fleshed it out a bit for you

Comment: possible values are 055B 60B 65B 70B upto 13B so I can have upto 26 Rows. It is completely possible that some of these rows are missing. If these rows are missing i would still like there values to be present in thr respective columns(SizeDesc50 ,SizeDesc55,SizeDesc60 etc) but in Count columns (SizeDesc50_count,SizeDesc55_count etc) I would default value to be 0. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have made the following query which seems to be working but can you please looking for some potential problem.
Thanks

```
SELECT distinct t1.PONumber, t1.LNSKUNumber, sum(t2.pair_count) AS [Size For 050], sum(t3.pair_count) AS [Size for 055],
sum(t4.pair_count) AS [Size for 060],sum(t5.pair_count) AS [Size for 065],sum(t6.pair_count) AS [Size for 070],
sum(t7.pair_count) AS [Size for 075],sum(t8.pair_count) AS [Size for 080],sum(t9.pair_count) AS [Size for 085],
sum(t10.pair_count) AS [Size for 090],sum(t11.pair_count) AS [Size for 095],sum(t12.pair_count) AS [Size for 100],
sum(t13.pair_count) AS [Size for 110],sum(t14.pair_count) AS [Size for 120],sum(t15.pair_count) AS [Size for 130]
FROM #tmptable t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #tmptable t2 ON t2.PONumber = t1.PONumber AND t2.LNSKUNumber=t1.LNSKUNumber AND t2.SizeDescription='050B'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #tmptable t3 ON t3.PONumber = t1.PONumber AND t3.LNSKUNumber=t1.LNSKUNumber AND t3.SizeDescription='055B'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #tmptable t4 ON t4.PONumber = t1.PONumber AND t4.LNSKUNumber=t1.LNSKUNumber AND t4.SizeDescription='060B'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #tmptable t5 ON t5.PONumber = t1.PONumber AND t5.LNSKUNumber=t1.LNSKUNumber AND t5.SizeDescription='065B'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #tmptable t6 ON t6.PONumber = t1.PONumber AND t6.LNSKUNumber=t1.LNSKUNumber AND t6.SizeDescription='070B'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #tmptable t7 ON t7.PONumber = t1.PONumber AND t7.LNSKUNumber=t1.LNSKUNumber AND t7.SizeDescription='075B'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #tmptable t8 ON t8.PONumber = t1.PONumber AND t8.LNSKUNumber=t1.LNSKUNumber AND t8.SizeDescription='080B'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #tmptable t9 ON t9.PONumber = t1.PONumber AND t9.LNSKUNumber=t1.LNSKUNumber AND t9.SizeDescription='085B'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #tmptable t10 ON t10.PONumber = t1.PONumber AND t10.LNSKUNumber=t1.LNSKUNumber AND t10.SizeDescription='090B'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #tmptable t11 ON t11.PONumber = t1.PONumber AND t11.LNSKUNumber=t1.LNSKUNumber AND t11.SizeDescription='095B'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #tmptable t12 ON t12.PONumber = t1.PONumber AND t12.LNSKUNumber=t1.LNSKUNumber AND t12.SizeDescription='100B'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #tmptable t13 ON t13.PONumber = t1.PONumber AND t13.LNSKUNumber=t1.LNSKUNumber AND t13.SizeDescription='110B'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #tmptable t14 ON t14.PONumber = t1.PONumber AND t14.LNSKUNumber=t1.LNSKUNumber AND t14.SizeDescription='120B'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #tmptable t15 ON t15.PONumber = t1.PONumber AND t15.LNSKUNumber=t1.LNSKUNumber AND t15.SizeDescription='130B'


    group by t1.SizeDescription, t1.PONumber, t1.LNSKUNumber
```

Comment: Not sure why you posted this as an answer as, other than adding of "Sum" on a column that wasn't part of the original query, it's the same solution.  It should work though.